# Angular js datagrid load on scroll gets similar chunk and then skip next chunk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hibernate, datagrid, infinite-scroll

I am making datagrid in materialize css and angular js with auto load more data on scroll I have used `infinite-scroll` library. working fine getting data and adding it to grid. But some times it duplicates the chunk and skip the next chunk.
here is my code:

```
var offset = 0;
$scope.getAll = function(){
        $http.get("list/"+offset+"/30").success(function(response){
        if(offset>0){
            angular.forEach(response, function(item){
                $scope.names.push(item);
            });
        }
        else
            $scope.names = response;
        offset+=30;
    });
}
```

and here is the server side code in hibernate:

```
public List<Employee> findAll(int offset, int limit) {
    log.debug("Employee findAll");
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    List<Employee> list = session.createCriteria(Employee.class).setMaxResults(limit).setFirstResult(offset).list();
    return list;
}
```

where can be the proble and how to resolve I am stuck here, please help me.
Thanks.